# Rでデーターフレームから重複した行を全て取りだすコード

Tags: r

A.sub <- A %>% dplyr::filter(kegg_compound != dup_u.df[1,]) %>%
               dplyr::filter(kegg_compound != dup_u.df[2,]) %>%
               dplyr::filter(kegg_compound != dup_u.df[3,]) %>%
               dplyr::filter(kegg_compound != dup_u.df[4,]) %>%
               dplyr::filter(kegg_compound != dup_u.df[5,])

Aはデーターフレームで、重複した遺伝子名が格納されたkegg_compound列があります。この列から、重複した遺伝子名を取りだすコードを書きたいのですが、うまくかけません。
dup_u.dfは、Aのkegg_compound列で重複した遺伝子名を格納したデーターフレームです。
  A1    <- A[duplicated(A$kegg_compound), ]    #A1には重複した最初の行が残る。
  dup   <- A1
  dup_u <- unique(dup$kegg_compound)
  dup_u.df <- data.frame(dup_u)
この例では、重複した遺伝子は、5個しかなかったため、一つずつ書き出したプログラムでも目的は達成されます。
もっと、重複した遺伝子が増えた場合、そもそも重複した遺伝子の数がわからない場合にも、対応できるプログラムにしたいと思っています。
Aは、文字型、ファクター型、int型が混在するデーターフレームです。
for文で以下のように書くと、ファクター型が強制的にint型に変換されてしまいます。
for(i in 1:nrow(dup_u.df)) {
        # B[i,] <- A[A$kegg_compound == dup_u.df[i,1], ] }

ご教授、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `duplicated` を使うのはどうでしょう。`unique(sort(A[duplicated(A$kegg_compound),]$kegg_compound))`

Answer (score 1):

「重複した行を取り出す」を，「重複が存在する行は(1行も残さず)削除する」なのかなと判断したのですが，あってますでしょうか．

*dplyr*を使っているようでしたので，以下のような感じではどうでしょうか．あと説明の都合上適当にサンプルを作ってます:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:6,
  kegg_compound = c("a", "b", "b", NA, "c", NA)
)
df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(kegg_compound) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(n() == 1) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id kegg_compound
#>   <int>        <fctr>
#> 1     1             a
#> 2     5             c
```

Comment: 重複する行を１行も残さず削除するで、良かったです。

Comment: ついでに、filter(n() == 1)とungroup()で、どのようなことをやっているのでしょうか？

Comment: dplyr::nは，そのグループ内のn数をカウントする関数です。
group_byした後に，filter関数内で上記のように指定すると，各グループのn数をカウントし，n=1のグループだけを残すようにフィルタリングします。
上記のコードでfilter(n() == 1)のかわりにmutate(n = n())とすると，理解しやすいかも知れません。
ungroupはグループ化していたのを解除しています。この後で予定しない挙動を抑制するために付けました